# CanCanCan gem with Devise + Omniauth Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancancan

Im using an Omniauth + Devise authentication system, where the user can register with his e-mail + password or with his Google+ account.

Now I need to use CanCanCan gem to check if the user that is loging in has permissions to go to the after login area, but I dont know where i can do that condition, in which file Devise stores the redirect after sucessfull login function?

Comment: A better approach is to add the authorization to the controller which handles your "after login area".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override Devise registration controller.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    '/home' # your path to redirect after signup
  end
end
```

You can define the access permissions in abilities.rb file.

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= user.new

    # Here you can define the permissions for home page for user
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the after_sign_in_path method in your Application Controller, where resource is your user:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.can? :show, ProtectedResource
      protected_area_path
    else
      denied_access_path
    end
  end
end
```

This will tell Devise where to redirect your user.